# PEM auto discovery not working for community postgres 15

Tags: postgresql, pem, enterprisedb, postgres15

We’re using postgres community version 15 on suse linux 15.3 . We have enabled system config file and started the database. But while we try to auto discover the server in Postgres Enterprise Manager we’re not able to do so. We’re getting “No servers were found by the agent on the system” error. How to fix this ?

We’re getting “/etc/postgres-reg.ini not found “ in worker log files

Comment: I guess you mesn PostgreSQL when you say "community postgres". Did you try asking the vendor of that Postgres Enterprise Manager?

Comment: Yes its PostgreSQL and we dont have support subscription

Comment: Perhaps use a different tool then.